# Fixed points in GAP

Tags: math-software, gap

How we can write a command in GAP for those permutations that are fixed,
For instance: if we have 
x:=(3,4)(5,7)(6.8)(9,12)(10,13)(11,14);
here 1 and 2 are fixed 
Moreover, if these point lies in other permutation i.e
t:=(1,2)(5,6)(7,8)(9,12),10,11)(13,14);

Here point 1 and 2 are fixed in x and lies in t permutations.

I want GAP to examine these points by itself.
How can we do it?

I am writing this programe like this

```
For i in x and i->i do    
  if i in t then     
    Print(i);    
  fi;    
od;
```

but it does'nt work.
Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you ask. It first defines a function to handle this problem in general, and then calls it for your specific `X` and `T`. It returns the answer as a list, since lists are easier to work with later (just printing the answers is fine, but what if you want to do something with them later? It is nice if they are stored somewhere). I include links to the reference manual in the following code:

```
gap> fixedByXandMovedByT := function( X, T )
>  return Filtered( MovedPoints( T ), i -> i = i^X );
> end;
gap> fixedByXandMovedByT( (3,4)(5,7)(6,8)(9,12)(10,13)(11,14), (1,2)(5,6)(7,8)(9,12)(10,11)(13,14) );
[ 1, 2 ]
```

If `i` is a positive integer and `X` is a permutation, then `i^X` means the evaluation of `X` at the point `i`. So `i = i^X` means `i` is a fixed point of `X`.  Yes, if you type this into gap it defines a function. The beginning of the function is marked by `function`, the value of the function is marked by `return` and the end of the function is marked by `end`.

The [tutorial on functions](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap4.html#X86FA580F8055B274) at the gap website, gap-system.org is pretty clear.

Comment: How did you define this program and what is the meaning of i^X here? Is it possible to define functions by ourself in GAP? Which material is best to read for me so that I could make functions by myself?

Comment: SchmidtI also want to know how do you use return and end commands here? I want to know the structure behind it.

Comment: is it possible to add one more permtations in Moved Points? for example in extended triangle group (2,3,7)=<x^2,t^2,y^3,(xy)^7,(xt)^2,(yt)^2> I want to examine those points in the coset diagram that fixed by x, are parallel to the axis of symmetry t, and are joined by the edge of y. So I amwriting here MovedPoints(T,Y) and making function(x,t,y).